# How to find and replace an entire line (random last 40 characters) with notepad++ using regex?

Tags: notepad++, regex, find-and-replace

I need to replace something like this:

```
userPassword: {SSHA}hLPcGtsS+sUhwlYq/23dsECuRGsvJj59OQXXJQ==
```

with something like this:

```
userPassword:funkypassword
```

I have tried some random stuff I've found, but no luck. What would the code be with regexp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match the last 40 characters of a line you would use the regex:

```
.{40}$
```

This means: "Match any character 40 times followed by end of line".

If you're interested in replacing the entire line you would use the regex

```
^(.*)(.{46})$
```

and a Replacement text of

```
first part:\1 second part:\2
```

would change your example text to

```
first part:userPassword:  second part:{SSHA}hLPcGtsS+sUhwlYq/23dsECuRGsvJj59OQXXJQ==
```

The brackets create a capture group and notepad++ replaces \n with the nth capture group.

Alternatevly, for your particular example (depends on what the other lines look like) you could use a pattern of

```
^(userPassword:).*$
```

Which simply matches all lines starting with "userPassword:".

Comment: Can you add some explanation of *why* this answers the question.

Comment: You sir rock, thank you! I ended up just using the ^(userPassword:).*$ the other method confused me a bit.